# Событие onmousemove окна

Tags: javascript

Почему если двигать указателем начав с одной точки, и потом вернутся в эту точку, то результат не 0?

```js
var i=0;
var n = 0;
function f2(Y, X) {
 if( Y > n) {
  ++i;
  n=Y;
 } 
 if( Y < n ) {
  --i;
  n=Y;
 }
 console.log(i);
}

onmousemove = function(e) { 
 if(n == 0) {
  n=e.clientY; 
 }
 f2(e.clientY,e.clientX); 
};
```

Comment: Без демонстрации проблемы - ничего сказать нельзя

Comment: Код весьма странный, переменные желательно называть нормально, а то приходится разбиратсья в том что могло быть понятно естественным образом. Присвоение в каждом if n=Y; тоже странное, можно вынести за if, либо в коде вообще ошибка. А логика кода сложнопонятна.

Comment: Не знаю, если двигать назад, то в списке числе есть и 0.